# Aligning acronyms to the left and long descriptions

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am trying to generate my list of acronyms.

I would like them to be all aligned to the left border of my page, with all the descriptions also aligned one below the other taking up the rest of the page.

I tried long-ragged, which puts my acronyms with a certain indent (which I do not like) and if there is a long description it goes to a new line instead of taking up the rest of the page.

I tried setting my own style but I get a double first letter (see below) so I am doing something wrong.

Here is the mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,nogroupskip,nopostdot]{glossaries} %ema 
\usepackage{glossary-longragged}
\usepackage{tabu}


\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ap}{AP}{apples potatoes}
\newacronym{bc}{BC}{beetroots and carrots are very good in soup}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
 {\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {p{0.15\linewidth}p{0.85\linewidth}}}%
 {\end{longtabu}}%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
% indicate what to do at the start of each logical group
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}{}
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
   \glstarget{##2}{##2}% Name
    & ##3% Description
    \\% end of row
    }
}


\begin{document}
\null
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type={acronym},style=longragged]%,style={longragged}]%, style={mystyle}]
\printglossary[type={acronym},style=mystyle]%,style={longragged}]%, style={mystyle}]

\end{document}
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

Any advice would be really helpful, 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by setting the mystyle2 as follows. I get a bad box warning though.

```
\begin{document}\newglossarystyle{mystyle2}{%
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
 {\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {p{0.15\linewidth}p{0.85\linewidth}}}%
 {\end{longtabu}}%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
% indicate what to do at the start of each logical group
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} 
   %\glstarget{##2}{##2}% Name
    & ##3% Description
    \\% end of row
    }
}
```